# Grouping by specific spreadsheet column in python

Tags: python, flask

If I have a table like this one,

```
TEST_ID COUNT   NAME        CHECK_TYPE  ITEMS
1       1       firstName   First Name  This is the first test
2       2       secondName  Second Name This is the second test
2       3       secondName  Second Name Tis is the third test
2       4       secondName  Second Name This is the fourth test
3       5       thirdName   Third Name  This is the fifth test
3       6       thirdName   Third Name  This is the sixth test
4       7       fourthName  Fourth Name This is the seventh test
4       8       fourthName  Fourth Name This is the eighth test
4       9       fourthName  Fourth Name This is the ninth test
4       10      fourthName  Fourth Name This is the tenth test
```

How can I group it so that my `CHECK_TYPE` values show up once?

My data read function is defined as,

```
def read_excel_data(flin='data_in.xlsx'):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(flin)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    header = []
    records = []
    for row in sheet.get_rows():
        if len(header) == 0:
            header.extend([x.value for x in row])
        else:
            dict_row = {x:y.value for x,y in zip(header,row)}
            records.append(dict_row)
    return records
```

My route is defined as,

```
@app.route('/show_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_data():
    excel_data = read_excel_data()
    return render_template('template.html', data = excel_data)
```

And in my HTML, I have it set as,

```
{%for alias in data%}
    <button name='{{alias.NAME}}' type='button' class='drop'>{{alias.CHECK_TYPE}}</button>
    <div class='panel'>
    {%for _item in data
        if _item.NAME == alias.NAME %} 
            <div>
                <br>
                <span name='item{{_item.COUNT}}'>{{_item.ITEMS}}</span>
                <select name='op{{_item.COUNT}}' class='menu' style='float:right'>
                    <option value=''>--Select one--</option>
                    <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                    <option value='No'>No</option>
                    <option value='NA'>N/A</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
{%endfor%}
</div>
{%endfor%}
</div>
```

The problem as it currently is, is that it creates as many `button` tags as there are `ITEMS` which is why I want to group by `NAME` or `CHECK_TYPE` so I only have the 4 buttons and 10 tests respectively under their appropriate button.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the question, you have a list of dicts and you want the unique ones to create buttons.  I assume your data already comes ordered for NAME.

Your markup really isn't the place for data processing.  You can use an OrderedDict to collect the unique pairs of NAME and CHECK_TYPE.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

...
def show_data():
   excel_data = read_excel_data()
   groups = list(OrderedDict((x['NAME'], x['CHECK_TYPE']) for x in data).items())
   return render_template('template.html', data = excel_data, groups=groups)
```

Now in your template

```
{%for alias_name, alias_check_type in groups%}
    <button name='{{alias_name}}' type='button' class='drop'>{{alias_check_type}}</button>
    ...
         if _item.NAME == alias_name %}
```